# Can I use PubNub for realtime data collection?

Tags: websocket, real-time, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I'm interested in collecting realtime data periodically (say every 1 min.) through a mobile app on my server. Can I use services like PubNub or Pusher for it or are they only for communication in the other direction - like sending push notifications from a server?

If I can use, could you please explain how exactly the setup would work?

Answer (score 0):

PubNub can provide bi-directional real-time datastreams on all devices, including mobile! Any phone (or server) can be a publisher, or a subscriber, or both.

You can choose your SDK of choice here http://www.pubnub.com/developers/ -- each client has docs for a simple hello world app.

If you need more assistance in getting setup with PubNub on mobile, just shoot us an email at support@pubnub.com and we will assist!

Comment: Thanks, could you also tell me what is the difference using PubNub vs. SalesForce?

Comment: Please tell us what you are using SalesForce for first.